# How to visualize csv data export from grafana using python

Tags: python, grafana

When i export csv data from grafana with API latency i saw two kind of value is seconds and millisecond, how to convert it to seconds using python.

```
time                 latency    
2022-09-30 06:20:00  957 ms
2022-09-30 07:25:00  6.63 s
2022-09-30 07:30:00  634 ms
```

More thing, with csv how i can visualize this data using python. plz

Comment: 1 second = 1000 ms...  that is the conversion. where are you stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload all the csv data into a **pandas dataframe** (you would use `pd.read_csv()` for this. From this you can use the `df.apply()` method to convert the seconds into miliseconds.

The `df.apply()` calls the user defined `convert() function` and you can see how that splits the `latency` column into `numbers` and `strings`.

This would work:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd


x = '''
time                 latency    
2022-09-30 06:20:00  957 ms
2022-09-30 07:25:00  6.63 s
2022-09-30 07:30:00  634 ms

'''

data = io.StringIO(x)

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

def convert(x:str):
    ''' convert string to number ms'''
    a, b = x.split(' ')
    a = float(a)
    if b =='s':
        a = a*1000
    return a

df['ms'] = df['latency'].apply(convert)
df
```

result

```
                 time latency      ms
0  2022-09-30 06:20:00  957 ms   957.0
1  2022-09-30 07:25:00  6.63 s  6630.0
2  2022-09-30 07:30:00  634 ms   634.0
```